# Change order of legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend

Example graph of my problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQirh.jpg (Code at bottom)

I would like to reorder my legend in a bar plot in ggplot2. Currently the fill is on a scale from "Inside", "Close" and "Far". This is basically the distance from a parking area of an escooter the actual scooter stands parked.

Now I want the Inside to fill the bottom (which is does), but I want "Close" and "Far" to switch places.

Anyone know how to do that?

Dummy code;

```
y <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
x <- c("Bolt", "Zipp", "Voi", "Bolt", "Zipp")
z <- c("Inside", "Inside", "Close", "Far", "Far")
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

dftest %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x,
             y = y,
             fill = z)) +
  labs(x = "Operator",
       y = "Amount of vehicles",
       fill = "Proximity") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discrete scales take a `limits` parameter, *"A character vector that defines possible values of the scale and their order"* . You can check `?ggplot2::scale_fill_grey` & `?ggplot2::discrete_scale` for reference.

Though when you have more categories you might want to use factors instead (i.e. `df %>% mutate(z = factor(z,levels = c("Far", "Close", "Inside")))` before piping it into `ggplot()` ),  factor levels set the default order in fill legend. And when dealing with factors, it's worth checking https://forcats.tidyverse.org/ .

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

y <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
x <- c("Bolt", "Zipp", "Voi", "Bolt", "Zipp")
z <- c("Inside", "Inside", "Close", "Far", "Far")
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x,
             y = y,
             fill = z)) +
  labs(x = "Operator",
       y = "Amount of vehicles",
       fill = "Proximity") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_grey(limits = c("Far", "Close", "Inside")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>